# How to detect updates/deletion in source and reflect in target using Talend

Tags: sql, sql-server, talend

I'll create a Talend job to run each time on the source table in SQL Server, in the first time all data will be with `Operation` I (Insert) for each row.

after that if any update occurs or delete, I need to change the operation only

Example:

This is the source table

[image: Source]

and this is the target table

[image: Target]

If I changed Google to Microsoft so if someone runs the job I need to change Operation in the target table to U (Update) with the new timestamp and so on.

After running the job, the target should be:

[image]

Comment: Since you mention SQL Server explicitely I've removed the unecessary *MySql* TAG

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15). See eg https://www.talend.com/resources/change-data-capture/

Comment: Thanks. CDC is really helpful.